# Awaitable method - call event when finished

Tags: c#, async-await

I have synchronous method, that calls async method:

```
private void Sync_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CancellationToken token = new CancellationToken();
    SyncAllMappings(token);            
}

async void SyncAllMappings(CancellationToken token)
{
    //create collection of tasks per each mapping
    IEnumerable<Task<Task>> tasks = SomeLogicHere();
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

The control returns to user before all tasks are done. 
Is it possible to get notified, when all tasks have finished? I would like to be able to call some other method, that would display text and enable few buttons, when all tasks finish (and all mappings are in sync).

`SyncAllMappings` method is in different assembly. Business and UI layers are separated. I don't want to call UI methods directly in `SyncAllMappings`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make your event handler async and await it and when tasks finishes do some UI work :

```
private async void Sync_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        CancellationToken token = new CancellationToken();
        await SyncAllMappings(token);            
        // do buttons enable disabling here
}
```

and your second method should be returning `Task` instead of `void`:

```
async Task SyncAllMappings(CancellationToken token)
{
        //create collection of tasks per each mapping
        IEnumerable<Task<Task>> tasks = SomeLogicHere();

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> The control returns to user before all tasks are done.

Yes, that's how async works. Instead of having an `async void` method, you should make it `async Task` - and then make your `Sync_Click` method async as well, so you can await the result:

```
private async void Sync_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CancellationToken token = new CancellationToken();
    await SyncAllMappings(token);            
    // Do whatever you want here, e.g. raising an event
}

async Task SyncAllMappings(CancellationToken token)
{
    //create collection of tasks per each mapping
    IEnumerable<Task<Task>> tasks = SomeLogicHere();

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```